# How is different flame color of alkali metals related to nuclear charge?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, metal

Why do different alkali metals produce different flame colors ?

According to my teacher,different atoms have different nuclear charge and due to difference in effective nuclear charge,the orbit to which an electron jumps differ even though energy provided from Bunsen flame is same.And on coming back it emits energy in the form of light.

This is very different from the reason I found when I googled my doubt. I wanted to know whether the explanation teacher me gave was correct.

Comment: There are different ways of explaining why electrons have different energy levels, but ultimately, the nuclear charge does determine the orbitals. What contradictory information did you find?

Comment: They produce different colours because different types of atoms have different and discrete energy levels. The photon is emitted when an electron moves from a higher level to a lower one. If you look up the (simple)  Bohr model of the atom you will see that the quantised (discrete) energy levels depend on $Z^2$ where $Z$ is the nuclear charge. You teachers explanation is correct.